# How to avoid hosts to acess my phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using XAMPP server and I add this line " Require all granted" in the file httpd-xamp.conf to allow hosts connected in my network by Lan to acess my files. And I want to restrict Hosts from acessing my admin server, such as XAMP page or phpmyadmin. How can I do please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a .htaccess file inside any directory you want to protect:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from XXX
```

Where XXX is your IP address

Comment: How to configure this .htaccess file?

Comment: Open windows notepad, create a file with the content I suggested and then save it as ".htaccess". To protect phpMyAdmin then put this file inside the phpMyAdmin directory

Comment: Finally I solved my problem by removing this line in the httpd-xampp-config file. Now I can acess my files directly to ex: "http:x.x.x.x/folder" and is restricted to acess my adim server 